# Lua script wont accept args

Tags: lua, minecraft, lua-5.2, opencomputers

I was trying to get an hologram projector working, but in run into these errors:

```
bad arguments #3 (number expected, got no value)
```

My script is:

```
local component = require("component")
local hologram = component.hologram

function setVoxel(x, y, z, value)
  print(x)
  print(y)
  print(z)
  print(value)
  local current = hologram.get(x, z)
  local positiveMask = bit32.lshift(1, y - 1)
  if value then
    hologram.set(x, z, bit32.bor(current, positiveMask))
  else
    local negativeMask = bit32.bnot(positiveMask)
    hologram.set(x, z, bit32.band(current, negativeMask))
  end
end

local args = {...}
print(args[1])
print(args[2])
print(args[3])
print(args[4])
setVoxel(tonumber(args[1]), tonumber(args[2]), tonumber(args[3]), args[4])
```

I used:

```
holo-set 8 16 20 true
```

The print commands returned:

```
8
16
20
true
```

but its not working.
I have checked the spelling.
Also the hologram is correctly initialized.

Comment: What does "opencomputers" mean? There's no description, and this is the only question with that tag. (I presume "minecraft" is somehow relevant, but I don't see anything about it in the question.)

Comment: @KeithThompson I imagine (read: My best guess) opencomputers is the mod he is using to get computers in Minecraft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means some function (what's the rest of the error?) which expected to get three arguments only got two.

Given that code snippet the only function I can see to which that might apply is `hologram.get`.

Which, given a quick look at the documentation (thank you Google), does in fact appear to require [three arguments](http://ocdoc.cil.li/component:hologram).

```
get(x:number, y:number, z:number):number
Returns the value at the specified position.
```